# read complex json file with spring batch

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-batch

i have a complex json file( with nested json arrays) structure like this:

```
{"persons":[ 
{"id":"1", "firstName": "X", "lastName": "X", "infos": [{"address":[{"city": "X", "country": "X"}]}]},
{"id":"2", "firstName": "Y", "lastName": "Y", "infos": [{"address":[{"city": "Y", "country": "Y"}]}]}
]}
```

I want to read each line ( one person) separately

So my spring batch configuration is like this

```
<bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters[file]}" />
    <property name="recordSeparatorPolicy" ref="recordPolicy" />
    <property name="lineMapper" ref="lineMapper" />
</bean>

<bean id="lineMapper"
    class="com.batchs.personJob.PersonLineMapper">
    <property name="delegate" ref="lineMapperType" />
</bean>

<bean id="lineMapperType"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.JsonLineMapper" />

<bean id="recordPolicy"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.separator.JsonRecordSeparatorPolicy" />
```

The mapper class looks like

```
    public class PersonLineMapper implements LineMapper<Person> {
    private JsonLineMapper delegate;

    public mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> personAsMap = delegate.mapLine(line, lineNumber);
        Person person = new Person();
        // map fields
        return person ;
    }

    public void setDelegate(JsonLineMapper delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
}
```

The problem is than the reader reads only one line (so one commit) because he reads the persons array in my json file like a whole line but i want read instead line per line ( one person at time)

How to do this ?

I have tried with a simple json file like this :

```
  { "id": "1",
      "firstName": "X",
      "lastName": "X"}
  { "id": "2",
      "firstName": "Y",
      "lastName": "Y"}
```

And it works good ... I read each person one by one

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have two options:

1. Write your own record separator that ignores the wrapper persons element/line.
2. Edit the file in a step before reading it to remove that wrapper line using something like a sed command.

If you choose option 2, you can execute it via the `SystemCommandTasklet` in the step before the one you actually process it in.

Comment: Thank you very much , i will try out the first option and back with results( because i cannot modify the file ). Should i use the default RecordSeparatorPolicy interface or the JsonRecordSeparatorPolicy class ? Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much , the first solution works . I manage to ignore the begin and the end of the file even if i did some makeshift job because the JsonRecordSeparatorPolicy unfortunately cannot handle json array by it's own

Comment: [ulquiorra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902509/ulquiorra) can you please share the solution

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be to run the file through a transform step to flatten the object structure, so you just have an array of People to deal with. Which should be fine, unless you're dealing with large files.

Comment: Thanks for your help . This solution works too ( i tried it ) but i will rather prefer use the record separator because my file is very large ( the step takes too long to proceed it )